# Setting prices in different websites in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

I'm trying to set upp three websites in Magento 2, which all sholud have different prices and different currencies.

Under `Stores > All Stores`, I have set up the following:

```
Swedish website     Sweden Store     Swedish Store View
Danish website      Denmark Store    Danish Store View
Norw. website       Norway Store     Norw. Store View
```

Under `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope`, I have selected "Website".

On the product edit page, the Price field is marked `[WEBSITE]`.
To set the price for the Danish website, I click the All Store View dropdown. But here I only find the Swedish Website. Which means that I cant find any way to set different prices for the product in the websites.

Anyone have any idea about how to get the other websites available in Store View dropdown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the product and check under the `Websites` tab if the product is associated to the Danish website. If it's not, associate it to the Danish website, save and when the page reloads you should be able to see `Danish` in the dropdown.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Have spent weeks in Magento without noticing that tab.

Comment: Holy crap I spend half day looking for an answer this is unexpected as I can see "Website B" everywhere in categories, configuration etc... on the top left Store View:  dropdown   apart from the product page thanks @Marius