# Magento 2 New Website not displaying in drop down on product page admin

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, multi-website

I've create new website but It's not showing the option the drop down admin for any given product please see screen shoot:

[image]

Now Take a look the next screen shoot it Shows everywhere this was taken from a category.
[image]

Does any body know what's the deal here cause I am lost any help please.

Thanks.

Comment: I just can't believe this is the way it is found an answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101400/setting-prices-in-different-websites-in-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the product and go into the Websites tab and add the product onto the Website that you want custom pricing on.

It will then appear in the dropdown :)

Comment: Thanks a lot , this helped.